# Google place auto complete not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an app. I want to suggest some city names when user enter characters.my code is-

```
public class GooglePlacesAutocomplete extends MainActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    Button btcancel;
    Button btsearch;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "GameDayWeather";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAU9ShujnIg3IDQxtPr7Q1qOvFVdwNmWc4";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_city);
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        btsearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        btcancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);  

        btcancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myint = new Intent(GooglePlacesAutocomplete.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myint);
                finish();
            }   
        });
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:in");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());

            System.out.println("URL: "+url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {

            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("==================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the auto complete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

My code is working fine. When I enter only two char of city name It show suggestions, but after enter third letter the suggestions are not displays. There are no error in Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```

in your xml

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
android:id="@+id/your_id" 
//your other properties

android:completionThreshold="1" />
```

or Programmatically set

```
autoCompView.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: Its not working again. I have added threshold in xml. For some time its worked, But now it has same problem. Please can u help.